# Where do utility methods fit in ASP.NET MVC setup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, directory-structure

Where do utility methods go in MVC setup? They are not Models, Views or Controller. They don't belong in those folders. So do is the only right thing to do is to keep utility methods outside your ASP.NET MVC project and put them into a project of their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how big your project is. If it's just a small project with a few utility methods, then what I normally do is put them in a folder called "Infrastructure" inside the MVC project.

The initial setup you get for an MVC project is only really a guide (with some exceptions), and you're free to add folders and put code in them if you want to.

If there's going to be a lot of supporting code, then a separate project might be cleaner and easier in the long run.

Comment: I'd go a step further and say it doesn't really matter. Moving the location of a class is a trivial refactor. If you get it wrong, just move it and have your IDE clean up all the references.